# dotnetopenid tutorial

Tags: dotnetopenauth

Pretty basic question, but can someone please point me to a constructive tutorial on how to implement and use dotnetopenid?

I'm struggling to find any real documentation that explains how to implement the thing.
I couldn't find anything on their website, and I've gone through a couple of the samples, but still can't work it out, and the included .chm file is just reference material, rather than a "getting started" guide.

Google searches are also failing me :(

Comment: DotNetOpenAuth has many facets: OpenID RP, OpenID OP, OAuth SP, OAuth Consumer, InfoCard RP, and then there are extensibility points.  There are lots of blog posts out there that help in some of these, but if you want a tutorial on relevant bits I recommend you specify what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on what you're trying to accomplish, as DotNetOpenAuth does a lot of things for a lot of people.

Perhaps I'll start a little table of scenarios, and people can add to this table as they discover tutorials:

- OpenID RP

  - [OpenID for ASP.NET MVC, A Quick Setup](http://andrewblogs.com/blog/openid-for-asp-net-mvc-a-quick-setup/) by andrew kharlamov
  - [Integrating OpenID in an ASP.NET MVC Application using DotNetOpenAuth](http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/899303.aspx) by Rick Strahl
- OpenID OP
- OAuth 1.0(a) Consumer
- OAuth 1.0(a) Service Provider
- OAuth 2.0 Client
- OAuth 2.0 Protected Resource Server
- OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server
- InfoCard RP

Comment: I think that is precisely the problem. How does one understand which scenario is suitable for what sort of requirement? Without this understanding, all of the above sounds just like arbitrary jargon. For example, if one just wants to add Google OAuth to their website, they would need to use OAuth 1.0(a) Consumer, etc. (I suppose). Note: Not criticizing your response, but OpenID documentation.

Comment: If you want to add "Google OAuth" to your site, that already must assume you know what you're talking about.  If you don't yet know all this jargon, we need to speak at a higher level: What scenario are you trying to enable for your users?  And yes, a tutorial that can guide people from the scenario level to the protocol level would be awesome.  I'd charge for that if I wrote it. :)