# Implementing DotNetOpenid in my asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to implement DotNetOpenid in my asp.net website. However, the more I try to read up on DotNetOpenid, the more confused I get. My initial goal is to allow user login process (similar to StackOverflow).

I attempted to get some help via this question [dotnetopenid tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882248/dotnetopenid-tutorial/3895442#3895442)
but was unsuccessful (since I am not using MVC)

How can I get a tutorial that would help me accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

I would first start at the developers site

1. [Coding Guidelines](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/coding-guidelines/)
2. [Quick Start](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/quickstart-environment/)
3. [Code Snippets](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

I have been posting my questions here [Support Forum](http://groups.google.com/group/dotnetopenid?pli=1). Pretty helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The [ASP.NET OpenID web site (C#)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/a527c9a4-6032-43ce-9284-d7e3174deb56?SRC=VSIDE) project template isn't a tuturial, but it does create a functioning OpenID ASP.NET web site.

I just installed it and was able to get a site up and running.  Here are a few gotchas that I ran into:

1. When you create a new project using the template, do not choose a deep path - this will create problems during database creation.
2. When you first run the application, you'll hit an exception - don't worry about it.  When you get the YSOD, simply browse to the Setup.aspx page mentioned in the instructions.
3. If you don't have an OpenID, you'll need to get one.  The initial page loaded after database creation has a 'Get OpenID' link if you need to get one.  It's a simple process and only takes a few minutes.

Once you get through that, you'll have a working implementation of an OpenID web site.

You might also want to check out the [DotNet OpenAuth ASP.NET Controls](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/a538d209-be29-4328-a903-1b729cdfeb14?SRC=VSIDE).

HTH

**Edit**

For anyone interested, there is also an [ASP.NET MVC 2 OpenID web site (C#)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/81153747-70d7-477b-b85a-0374e7edabef) template.  I'm surprised @Andrew Arnott answered the other question and didn't mention these, since he is the author.

Comment: @Andrew Arnott answered which question?

Comment: @user279521, Oops, sorry - thought you asked the question you linked to in your question.